# Passing exclude list to the Update Membership Statuses scheduled job

Tags: civimember, scheduled-job, status

We added a special pending memberhsip status for a client, but because it is not one of the default statuses, it is not getting excluded when the Update Membership Statuses scheuled job runs and is therefore getting processed. I noticed that the scheduled job *should* be able to take a parameter with an *array* of ints to tell the job what statuses to ignore, but it appears that the input parameter doesn't actually take an *array* of ints, but only a single one (which isn't helpful). Here is the error the gets returned when I run the scheduled job with the param:

*Summary: Finished execution of Update Membership Statuses with result: Failure, Error message: exclude_membership_status_ids is not a valid integer*

Here is the parameter I added to the scheduled job.

*exclude_membership_status_ids=[4,5,6,7,8]*

I also tried it without the square brackets:

*exclude_membership_status_ids=4,5,6,7,8*

What am I missing? Is this a bug in the code? How can I exclude my new membership status from being processed (and being set to New even though it is a special Pay Later pending status)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it should work if you change 'ids' to 'id' as per below

exclude_membership_status_id=[4,5,6,7,8]

I tried on a local copy, executed the job and it did process - details below

```
Parameters raw (from db settings): 
exclude_membership_status_id=[4,5]

Parameters parsed (and passed to API method): 
a:2:{s:7:"version";i:3;s:28:"exclude_membership_status_id";s:5:"[4,5]";}

Full message: 
Finished execution of Update Membership Statuses with result: Success (Processed 26 membership records. Updated 0 records.)
```

Hope that will work for you too.